# Migrate VM from MS Virtual Server 2005 to Hyper-V?

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines, microsoft-virtual-server

Is there a supported path of migrating a virtual machine running in Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1, to Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1? The guest is running a version of Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [SCVMM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793147.aspx) can V2V a MS Virtual Server 2005 VM to Hyper-V. You can also treat the VM like it's physical and P2V it, but that generally takes a much longer time to convert that way.

Comment: -1. This is not a solution, even if a not educated OP answer s it. It requires and EXPENSIVE additoinal piece of software that the poster has not said he uses (and that is not something a small Hyper-V install would use).

Comment: I suppose "expensive" depends on the size of your budget, but I've never seen a quote for it that would warrant it to be written in all capital letters :)

Comment: Well, Hyper-V costs 0 and someone using from Virtual Server unlikely runs a 100 machine farm, you know. In this case, without SPLA, this is a ridiculous additional expense.

Comment: The OP may have awarded the delivery of the answer as well. Attitude matters.

Comment: The question was not about cost, it was about migration paths. I suggest we all stay on topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official MS guide for this type of migration which describe all the necessary requirements and steps to be performed:

[Virtual Machine Migration Guide: How To Migrate from Virtual Server to Hyper-V](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296684(v=ws.10).aspx)